# Question about group of covering/deck transformations and lifting

Tags: algebraic-topology

Suppose $E$ is path-connected and $p:E\to B$ is a covering map. Then the group $G$ of covering transformations is the group of homeomorphisms $f:E\to E$ where $p\circ f=p$.

The question is asking me to show that $f$ is uniquely determined by its effect on a single point $e\in E$. What theorems about lifting should be considered?

Comment: use uniqueness of path lifting